# how to insert multiple values which is the output of a select query

Tags: sql

```
Select 
cast(ltrim(rtrim(Substring(string,charindex('my',string)+len('my')+5,
charindex('for the company',string)-charindex('my',string)+len('my')-9))) as datetime)
 from table

Select 
cast(ltrim(rtrim(Substring(string,charindex('company',string)+len('company')+1,
len(String)-charindex('company',string)+len('company')-9)))as varchar) 
from description
```

this 2 queries has a set of rows  as output.

I want to insert these values to another table using single insert.
What i did is:

```
insert into table2(orderid,orderdate) 
 Select
cast(ltrim(rtrim(Substring(String, len('The order number')+1,
CHARINDEX ( 'as been created at', String) - len ('as been created at')))) as int)
,
cast(ltrim(rtrim(Substring(string,charindex('at',string)+len('at')+5,
charindex('for the company',string)-charindex('at',string)+len('at')-9))) as datetime)
from description
```

but its not inserted..its showing error like The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value..
Is there any another way to insert this?

Comment: What does the data in the "string" column look like?

Comment: string is The order number 634528 has been created at 2011-03-02 21:11:15.367 for the company Toyato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert output from your two queries into a single table, the data types and number of columns from these queries should match with that of the table. You can use convert

```
CONVERT(
  DATETIME,ltrim(rtrim(Substring(
  string,charindex('at',string)+len('at')+5, 
  charindex('for the company',string)-charindex('at',string)+len('at')-9)))
,112)
```

for your datetime column and try (provided your target table has a datetime column for OrderDate).

Comment: please help me... Why you are not accepting questions from my Account? Kindly let me know about this. please.

Comment: @agens: What are you talking about? I did not get what you are asking ... which questions?

Answer (score 1):

when inserting a datetime you should specify a string that is SQL compliant i.e.

```
'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
```

I suspect that the `CAST` function cant convert the type specified. However you dont need to convert to a datetime, you can simply insert the string representation of the datetime.

Other issues you may encounter are the casting of ltrim(rtrim()) to an int. `LTRIM`, `RTRIM` both return a varchar. `CHARINDEX` already returns an int.

Ensure your types are consistent